# How to copy object, binary and elf files to a directory in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am using gcc-arm and I am trying to copy the object files during the build to a separate directory.

```
OBJS = example.o

OBJDIR = /home/repos/build/

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c 
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 
$(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $*.d

%.o: %.s
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


ELF = main.elf
$(ELF): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS) 

BIN = main.bin
%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@
```

Comment: Please provide more information about how you invoke `make` as well as details of any error/warning messages.

Comment: I call 
make all, there is no errors, it built well but my problem is that object files are in the same directory not in the object directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a target in another directory you have to tell make that's what you want to do.  This:

```
OBJS = example.o
  ...
$(ELF): $(OBJS)
```

tells make you want to build a file `example.o`, which is just a file in the same directory.  If you want to build a file in a different directory, you have to ask for it:

```
OBJDIR = /home/repos/build/

OBJS = $(OBJDIR)example.o
```